# GeoPDF added into QGIS gives a broken raster; GeoReferencing it gives an invisible output

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, geopdf

I've been attempting to add a GeoPDF to my QGIS 3.16.14 project. The PDF is available here: https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/reach_irq_map_mosul_city_reference_08nov2017.pdf

Everything except the background loads and is editable.

However, the base map which has the spatial information appears as two strips.

[image]

This makes the image unusable for me as I need to trace the neighborhood outlines for a project. I've added the GeoPDF both with drag and drop, and by using the Add Vector Layer and Add Raster Layer, none work.

I've alternatively tried to save the layered GeoPDF into a non-geo TIFF, and georeference that into the project. For some reason, the georeferenced TIFF appears as a layer, but is invisible. Reloading it back into the project doesn't make a difference.

Could anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Works for me without issues.

Comment: Could you tell what version you are running and how you imported the file into QGIS?

Comment: Version 3.18.3, by using Layer-Add raster layer with default settings. Drag-and-drop into the QGIS project works as well.